# shellcheck: "In POSIX sh, ulimit -H is not supported"

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, posix, ulimit

I am using shellcheck to fix warnings in a sh script.  The script checks for the hard fd limit with:

`ulimit -H -n`

It sets the soft fd limit with:

`ulimit -n "$MAX_FD"`

This generates the shellcheck warnings:

`In POSIX sh, ulimit -H is not supported. [SC2039]`

`In POSIX sh, ulimit -n is not supported. [SC2039]`

What is the portable way to both get the hard resource limit and set the soft resource limit in POSIX sh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, strictly speaking, the [POSIX `ulimit`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/ulimit.html) only seems to know the `-f` option (max file size), so I suppose the answer is "none".

In practice, all shells I have on Linux (Bash, Busybox, Dash, Ksh, mksh, yash, zsh), have a builtin `ulimit` that supports `-H`, `-S`, and `-n`.

I don't know about non-Linux systems for sure, but the [FreeBSD man page for `sh(1)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sh&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD%2012.0-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html) also mentions those, and on OpenBSD, [`/bin/sh` appears to be ksh](https://man.openbsd.org/sh.1), which also supports them.

Comment: so in practice just ignore this warning without ill effect?  what about scripts that may run on BSDs?

Comment: @DylanCali, looks like something you'll have to check on each OS. Or just use Bash/ksh or such. The [underlying system calls](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/setrlimit.html) are in POSIX, so I suppose the shells that support `-HSa` it would support them on all OSes. Maybe.

Comment: came across [this](http://openbsd-archive.7691.n7.nabble.com/Why-does-OpenBSD-lack-a-man-page-for-ulimit-td238944.html) openbsd thread from several years ago where Theo de Raadt indicates ksh ulimit semantics and [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/openbsd/comments/6zr2ps/whats_the_default_shell_in_openbsd/) reddit thread that indicates on openbsd sh is really just ksh in disguise... so seems to be safe to assume these options there as well

Comment: It is important to _read the second paragraph_ of the OpenBSD `sh` manual.

Comment: @JdeBP, well, that's of course one way of writing documentation. My fault for just grepping to the point. Thanks.

Comment: Just to confirm that `ulimit -H` seems to be working in OpenBSD `sh`.  It's not documented in `sh(1)`. From the manual: This version of sh is actually ksh in disguise.  As such, it also
supports the features described in ksh(1).  This manual page describes
only the parts relevant to a POSIX compliant sh.  **If portability is a
concern, use only those features described in this page.**